# How exactly do I have to use HStoreField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-hstore

I'm using the latest version of Django and DRF. But after running it I'm getting this error:

class HStoreDescriptor(models.fields.subclassing.Creator):
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models.fields' has no attribute 'subclassing'

I'm not sure how to use HStoreField and create an extension using migration. This is my structure of the file.

```
webhook10/
 |-- tutorial/
 |    |-- slack/                
 |    |    |-- migrations/
 |    |    |    +-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- admin.py
 |    |    |-- apps.py
 |    |    |-- models.py
 |    |    |-- tests.py
 |    |    |-- urls.py
 |    |    +-- views.py
 |    |-- tutorial/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- settings.py
 |    |    |-- urls.py
 |    |    |-- wsgi.py
 |    +-- manage.py
 +-- venv/
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django_hstore import hstore

class WebhookTransaction(models.Model):
    UNPROCESSED = 1
    PROCESSED = 2
    ERROR = 3

    STATUSES = (
        (UNPROCESSED, 'Unprocessed'),
        (PROCESSED, 'Processed'),
        (ERROR, 'Error'),
    )

    date_generated = models.DateTimeField()
    date_received = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    body = hstore.SerializedDictionaryField()
    request_meta = hstore.SerializedDictionaryField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=STATUSES, default=UNPROCESSED)

    objects = hstore.HStoreManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.date_event_generated)

class Message(models.Model):
    date_processed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    webhook_transaction = models.OneToOneField(WebhookTransaction)

    team_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_domain = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    channel_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    channel_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
    trigger_word = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.user_name)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from slack.models import WebhookTransaction, Message

class WebhookTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WebhookTransaction
        fields = '_all_'

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '_all_'
```

Please tell what changes I can do? If you want more information please do ask.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `'django.contrib.postgres'` in your **INSTALLED_APPS**.
2. Connect Postgresql and create hstore extension:

   `sudo su - postgres
   \c database;
   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;`
3. In your models.py:

   `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField
   class Section(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
       parameters = HStoreField(blank=True,null=True)`
4. Run following commands on the terminal:

   `python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate`
5. By default, it gives you ugly text-area to write json key-value pairs. If you like a fancy hstore widget, then you can install it:

   1. `pip install django-admin-hstore-widget`.
   2. Add django_admin_hstore_widget to your INSTALLED_APPS ( in settings.py )
   3. Then in admin.py of your app, add this.

   from your_app.models import Section

   from django import forms

   from django_admin_hstore_widget.forms import HStoreFormField

   ```
   class SectionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
       parameters= HStoreFormField()

       class Meta:
           model = Section
           exclude = ()


   @admin.register(Section)
   class SectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       form = SectionAdminForm
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to import django_hstore

Add `'django.contrib.postgres'` in your INSTALLED_APPS.

If hstrone not enabled on Postgres , Run sql script: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore`

On Model: Add: `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField`

Add Field: `objects  = HStoreField()`

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.HStoreField)

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore
  File "<console>", line 1
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore
                   ^

Comment: `CREATE EXTENSION` is a SQL command, not a python command. You run it in a database shell, either direct through `psql` or via `manage.py dbshell` if you have that properly configured.

Comment: @siddhantSingh either psql or via manage.py dbshell as wmorrell said

Comment: Do I have to create superuser before that because If I'm trying to save my model it doesn't let me run anything not even manage.py dbshell. @wmorrell

Comment: You cannot use any of the model code until you configure the database to support it. Regardless, `HSTORE` is practically deprecated in favor of `JSONB` at this point, so as long as you are using PostgreSQL 9.2 or above, try looking at `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield