# Implementing PostgreSQL HStore in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, hstore, django-hstore

I found some couple of packages to implement PostgreSQL HStore in Django from [djangopackages.org](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/postgresql-integration/). The most stared and most forked package was last updated in March 2, 2017 [DJANGO-HSTORE]. I think it is not maintained regularly. But as it at the top of the list I am confused about that should I use it in my project or there is a better option for me.

Which is the best and handy way to implement PostgreSQL HStore in Django?

Comment: I have answered the similar question, you can follow the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59152560/7486447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while that django added bult-in support for hstore: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield)

Comment: wow! There is a built-in support? It will be more handy! But please clear my another confusion. If there is a built-in support for this then why there exist entire separate packages (like [django-hstore](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore)) for this task?

Comment: hstore was recently added to django (not very recent but older versions didn't have that) so you had to use 3rd party packages

Comment: You may want to consider Django's built in support for JSONB for future flexibility: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/07/14/choosing-nosql-hstore-json-jsonb/